# CTLineGetGlyphRuns strange behaviour with NSAttributedString

Tags: objective-c, nsattributedstring, glyphrun

I have a string, let's say `"Hello"` I need to append in front and at the end `","` so the string looks like this: `",Hello,"` now I want the text to be white and the "," in different color. So I do something like this:

```
[attributedString addAttribute:(__bridge NSString *)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor whiteColor] range:NSMakeRange(range.location+1, range.length-1)];
[attributedString addAttribute:(__bridge NSString *)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor yellowColor] range:NSMakeRange(range.location, 1)];
[attributedString addAttribute:(__bridge NSString *)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor yellowColor] range:NSMakeRange(range.length-1, 1)];
```

later I do all the stuff with the `CTFrameSetterRed`, `CGContextRef`

```
CTLineRef line = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex((CFArrayRef)lines, index);
CFArrayRef glyphRuns = CTLineGetGlyphRuns(line);
CFIndex glyphCount = CFArrayGetCount(glyphRuns);
```

And in this `",Hello,"` example the glyphCount returns `3` HOWEVER! when I change the code to:

```
[attributedString addAttribute:(__bridge NSString *)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor whiteColor] range:NSMakeRange(range.location+1, range.length-1)];
[attributedString addAttribute:(__bridge NSString *)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor whiteColor] range:NSMakeRange(range.location, 1)];
[attributedString addAttribute:(__bridge NSString *)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor whiteColor] range:NSMakeRange(range.length-1, 1)];
```

(now the whole message ",Hello," is white, thats the only change) the glyphCount returns `1`
Why is it so and how to avoid it? This looks rather strange.